# Testing static methods of 3rd party Java SDKs

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I've been working with Java, specifically in Android, for a few months now and I've found that working with PowerMockito is something I'd rather not do. The complexities of keeping it working have outweighed any benefit of it. I also think I'd agree with most of the comments I've read on Stackoverflow that say not to use PowerMockito, so please keep that in mind when answering my question. I am looking for guidance to testing without PowerMockito.

My question is, when writing code that interfaces with a 3rd party SDK that has some static method, how would you test it? Specifically, when it seems the only thing really worth testing is a behaviour? ie that the static method was called?

I can and do put these 3rd party services behind adapter classes usually. And I can test that my adapter was called. But how do you live with not ever being able to test that the 3rd party itself was called and maybe confirm which arguments it was called with? Is this the only thing available in my toolbox? to limit logic as much as possible so that the untested area is less likely to fail?

When explaining this to someone coming from a dynamically typed language would you just say that the test wasn't valuable? I'm thinking at this point that these kind of tests are low value, but I can understand why others would want to test this kind of thing. Its the kind of test I've seen written a lot in Ruby projects I've worked on.

Comment: My opinion - if all one of your methods does is to call some method of the library, then unit testing it is not an economical use of your time.  Spend your time unit testing code that actually has its own logic.

Comment: Thanks @DawoodibnKareem this reflects what I'm thinking :)

Comment: Upvoting just for your assessments on that specific mocking framework.

Comment: Hopefully the 3rd party SDK has its own tests.  (Although I've seen plenty of commercial SDKs that probably don't.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing I have done in the past in similar situations:

- created a tiny wrapper interface and an impl class calling that static method; and test verifying that the wrapper is called
- a single test case that invokes that impl class and thereby the real static method.

If one is "lucky" that call has an observable effect, for example some exception gets thrown (that is the problem with a lot of static code in my context - it simply breaks unless the whole stack is running). And then you check for that. But I also agree: there isn't much value in doing so. It proofs correct plumbing, at the cost of being subject to change whenever the behavior of that static method changes.

Comment: I think this is the right answer for me! This is what I've been doing also, but I hadn't considered checking an exception was thrown. (Most of the SDKs I've used also throw exceptions). Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome. I really don't like such solutions; but so at least: it seems to helpful to others as well ;-)